# Hml file stored in OnedDrive with links to images stored in same folder not working

Tags: html, onedrive

I'm storing html files to a OneDrive folder.

The repro is trivial.
In your onedrive, create a folder named repro.
Upload one image, for example image.jpg.
In this folder, create an html page and try to dislay the image.

Link is broken.

My page contains these 2 kind of links.

1. This link is not clickable (but I right click, open in new tab, it works)
   <img width="100%" src="/personal/user_test_domain_com/Documents/repro/image.jpg">
2. This image gets broken. But if I right click, open image in new tab, it works.
   Click link to open the image

It looks like Onedrive has a kind of protection that prevents displaying the images stored in onedrive. I tried to store the image in Style Assets folder as well and it didn't work.

We are developping a product where an archive of a discussion is stored as an html file in the personal onedrive of the user.
It is important that the images be displayed correctly.

What syntax should we use? Is there a way to use and iframe, an embedded component to display the images correctly in the page.
Images and html files are stored in the same location in the onedrive of the user.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution? Thank you.